# Show a hierarchy in PHP

Tags: php, hierarchy

I have a database which stores a hierarchy of foods.

```
Category(id_cat,name_cat);
his_low_cat(id_cat,id_low_cat);
```

A category can have 0..n low category. If it had no lower category I do a `id_cat,-1` field in `his_low_cat`.

I do not know if it's possible but I would like to show it in a kind of "pulldown menu"
(if you have any other idea on how to show a full hierarchy please suggest it)

Like this :

```
echo " <div id=\"menu\"> 
   <ul class=\"niveau1\"> 
      <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Food\">Food</a> 
         <ul class=\"niveau2\"> 
            <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Sous menu 1.1\">Sous menu 1.1</a> 
               <ul class=\"niveau3\"> 
                  <li><a href=\"Sous sous menu 1.1.1\">Sous sous menu 1.1.1</a></li>  
               </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li><a href=\"Sous menu 1.2\">Sous menu 1.2</a></li> 
         </ul> 
      </li> 
   </ul> 
</div>";
```

My first cat is "food" and then it derives into 4 lowers categories, which derive themselves in more.

The problem is that it must be dynamic and load field from my database.
The goal would be to be able to catch the clicked value and use it in another .php

How would I do this?

Comment: I thought about doing it in a recursive way by only showing a text, no menu. but this is rly tricky..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is definitely the way to go with this problem, I've coded up this solution:

```
<?php
function nestElements($elements, $depth=0)
{
    foreach($elements as $elementName=>$element)
    {
         echo str_repeat("\t", $depth).'<ul class="niveau'.($depth+1).'">'."\n";
         if(is_array($element))
         {
               echo str_repeat("\t", $depth+1)."<li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"${elementName}\">${elementName}</a>\n";
               nestElements($element, $depth+2);
               echo str_repeat("\t", $depth+1)."</li>\n";
         }
         else
         {
               echo str_repeat("\t", $depth+1)."<li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"${element}\">${elementName}</a></li>\n";
         }
         echo str_repeat("\t", $depth)."</ul>\n";
    }
}
nestElements(array("Food"=>array("Meat"=>array("Poultry"=>array("Chicken"=>"Meat/Poultry/Chicken"), "Beef"=>array("Hamburgers"=>"Meat/Beef/Hamburgers", "Steak"=>"Meat/Beef/Steak")), "Dairy"=>array("Cow"=>"Dairy/Cow", "Sheep"=>"Dairy/Sheep")), "name"=>"url"));
?>
```

Testing with this:

```
<?php
nestElements(array("Food"=>array("Meat"=>array("Poultry"=>array("Chicken"=>"Meat/Poultry/Chicken"), "Beef"=>array("Hamburgers"=>"Meat/Beef/Hamburgers", "Steak"=>"Meat/Beef/Steak")), "Dairy"=>array("Cow"=>"Dairy/Cow", "Sheep"=>"Dairy/Sheep")), "name"=>"url"));
?>
```

Results in:

```
<ul class="niveau1">
    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Food">Food</a></li>
    <ul class="niveau2">
            <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Meat">Meat</a></li>
            <ul class="niveau3">
                    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Poultry">Poultry</a></li>
                    <ul class="niveau4">
                            <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Meat/Poultry/Chicken">Chicken</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="niveau3">
                    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Beef">Beef</a></li>
                    <ul class="niveau4">
                            <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Meat/Beef/Hamburgers">Hamburgers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="niveau4">
                            <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Meat/Beef/Steak">Steak</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class="niveau2">
            <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Dairy">Dairy</a></li>
            <ul class="niveau3">
                    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Dairy/Cow">Cow</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="niveau3">
                    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="Dairy/Sheep">Sheep</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="niveau1">
    <li class="sousmenu"><a href="url">name</a></li>
</ul>
```

To parse it you'd have to make a mod_rewrite which redirects to index.php?r=TheURL and from their, explode the r parameter using "/" as the delimeter, then you have a list of menus and submenus that the clicked link was from.  By adding another parameter the url coul be automatically generated.

Edit: Fixed problem with original code output seen below

```
<li class="sousmenu"><a href="Sheep">Sheep</a></li>
<li class="sousmenu"><a href="Dairy/Sheep">Sheep</a></li>
```

To generate the array:

```
<?php
function genArray(&$targetArray, $parentID=null){
    $res=(is_null($parentID))?mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE id_cat NOT IN (SELECT id_low_cat FROM hislowcat) ORDER BY id_cat DESC;"):mysql_query("SELECT *, (SELECT name_cat FROM categorie WHERE id_cat= '".$parentID ."') AS name_cat FROM hislowcat WHERE id_cat= '" .$parentID ."'");
    if(!is_null($parentID) && !mysql_num_rows($res))
    {
        $res3=mysql_query("SELECT name_cat FROM categorie WHERE id_cat='${parentID}';");
        $row3=mysql_fetch_array($res3);
        $targetArray[$row3['name_cat']]=$row3['name_cat'];
        return;
    }
    while(($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)))
    {
        //echo $row->name_cat;
        if(is_null($parentID))
        {
             if(!isset($targetArray[$row['name_cat']]))
             {
                   $targetArray[$row['name_cat']]=array();
             }
             genArray($targetArray[$row['name_cat']], $row['id_cat']);
        }
        else
        {
             genArray($targetArray[$row['name_cat']], $row['id_low_cat']);
        }
    }
}
$array=array();
genArray($array);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Notice how $targetArray is set up as a reference, this way we can treat it one-dimensionally.

Comment: wow, this is rly appreciated. So all i need is to load my datas into a well structured array.

Comment: No problem, and yup pretty much.  I just updated the answer because I'm not sure if <ul><li></li><ul></ul></ul> is the same as <ul><li><ul></ul></li>.

Comment: well, i spent some hours trying to generate my arrays.. it's rly tricky. if it's not too much asking, how would you do? I got 2 tables. Category(id_cat,name_cat); his_low_cat(id_cat,id_low_cat); it's recursive aswell

Comment: following your example. it's like having in my category table : id_cat = 0, name_cat = food; id_cat = 1, name_cat = Meat; id_cat = 2; name_cat = Poultry; id_cat = 3, name_cat = Dairy... and in my his_low_cat : id_cat = 0, id_low_cat = 1; id_cat = 0, id_low_cat = 3; id_cat = 1, id_low_cat = 2 ... I d like to have an array with your structure : array("Food"=>array("Meat"=>array("Poultry"=>array("Chicken" => array("machin" => "machin")), "Beef"=>array("Hamburgers" => "Hamburgers", "Steak" => "Steak")), "Dairy"=>array("Cow" => "Cow", "Sheep" => "Sheep"))));

Comment: I updated a little bit, it's not functional as is, but it's about as close as I can get without testing/experimenting myself.

Comment: yea thanks, i tried my best but still failing... [link](https://titanpad.com/functionarray) i know that i'm quite close .. but something is wrong when inserting values in the array. and i don't know what to do in the else statement.. if you re highly motivated,i added a .sql

Comment: Updated with code that seems to work.  It looks really ugly though haha.

Comment: oh my dayum THIS WORK! you spent so much time and effort on it... this is really appreciated! Aliment is doubled but it doesnt matter ;). I owe you one!